# Debug bFLT in qemu-arm-static

Tags: ida, debugging, arm, gdb, qemu

I have bFLT  binary (into linux-arm arch.) that I can run with `qemu-arm-static` .

I want to debug that binary dynamically with GDB.

I know I can debug binary with qemu like `qemu-arm-static -g 1111 <binary path>`

The problem is that when I run `gdb-multiarch` with that bFLT binary gdb tell me that `<binary path> not in executable format: file format not recognized`

How can I debug with GDB bFLT binary?

Answer (score 1):

bFLT format is mostly used by the uCLibc based tool chains and even there the build happens to ELF which is then converted to bFLT, so it’s unlikely you’ll find a GDB which supports bFLT directly. However, you may be able to debug it by attaching to the QEMU’s GDB port (`target remote` command).

Comment: So maybe do you know a tool that convert bFLT to ELF? So I will debug it as ELF?

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom I don't know of such tool and not sure if it's possible; some information is lost completely when converting to bFLT.